# Mongodb Find count of occurrence of all unique list elements

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have data like below in mongodb:

```
{
  "name":["apple", "banana", "oranges", "grapes"]
},
{
  "name":["apple", "banana"]
},
{
  "name":["apple", "oranges"]
},
{
  "name":["oranges", "banana"]
},
{
  "name":["grapes", "banana"]
}
```

I want to aggregate and get result as following:-

```
{
  "apple": 3,
  "banana":4,
  "grapes": 3,
  "oranges": 3
}
```

I tried something like this:-

```
db.collection.aggregate([
            {"$unwind": "$name" },
            {"$group": {"_id":  "$name", "count": { "$sum": 1 }}}
        ]]
```

This results in in accurate data, some of the unique elements get missed. Not sure what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) to merge all aggregates into single document and then run [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) on it. Additionally you can use [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to promote new structure to root level:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$unwind": "$name" },
    { $group: { _id: "$name", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
    { $group: { _id: null, names: { $push: { k: "$_id", v: "$count" } } } },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$names" } } }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0lJhOwUXOz3)